# natbib question: Johnson 1990a, b in order of appearance

Tags: bibtex, natbib, sorting

I have an issue with the `natbib` package.

In my reference list, multiple entries occur of the same author in the same year.
I'd like to control which one is Johnson (1990a), and which one is Johnson (1990b).
The BibTeX compiler creates an order for them, putting the first paper in the reference list (which incidentally is also published earlier in 1990 than the other) as 1990b.

I'd like to be able to control the a,b order, preferably without changing it manually in the `.bbl` file. Does anyone know how to do this? What ordering scheme does the compiler use by default?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Next to the linked question, maybe you can specify the field `month`.